# Android 2.3.3 list view animation doesn't work properly

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with animate insertion a row to list view.

```
//Insertion to database code
listView.invalidate();
MainActivity.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View view = listView.getChildAt(i);
    int position = listView.getPositionForView(view);
    long viewItemId = MainActivity.this.adapter.getItemId(position);
    if (viewItemId == newId) {
        AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        alphaAnimation.setDuration(800);
        view.setAnimation(alphaAnimation);
    }
}
```

This code works on android 4.3.1. But doesn't work on Android 2.3.3.
On Android 2.3.3 animation works, but it is applied to the another view. Please help.

Comment: If I use lvData.invalidate() and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the code and extract other lines to Handler this solution works for me. What is a problem?